# AWS DynamoDB checking uniqueness before adding new item

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to check whether id(primary-key) of new item is uniq or not before adding into dynamoDB

what could be best option for both performance and cost wise.

---

Possible options to check uniqueness of primary-key can be...

1) Get (if empty array returns, it means there are no matching data. which also means it is uniq)

2) Scan (obvious, worst idea for both performance and cost)

3) Query

---

++ my another thought is, if there has any way to forcibly ignore incoming request in DynamoDB settings(discard incoming request or send error message), logic could be much simpler.

In normal RDB, if we try to add new item with existing primary key, Database will return error message without changing original data stored in database.

however, in DynamoDB, whether we Put item or Update item with existing primary key, it just silently changes original data stored in database.

have any idea?

Comment: Your options 1 and 3 are the same thing, they are both doing a Query operation on the primary key. Your option 2 is not even worth considering if you have a primary key value to look up.

Answer (score 4):

As you mentioned, DynamoDB will update an item with the primary key you provide if it already exists. The article below shows you how you can make a conditional PUT request which will fail upon trying to insert an item that already exists (based on the primary key).

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_PutItem.html

> To prevent a new item from replacing an existing item, use a conditional expression that contains the attribute_not_exists function with the name of the attribute being used as the partition key for the table. Since every record must contain that attribute, the attribute_not_exists function will only succeed if no matching item exists.